# Flutter type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int', trying to get complicated JSON into flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my json here: https://my-json-server.typicode.com/fluttirci/testJson/db

This code only works if there is an only one json object however, with this employees JSON, it doesn't work. Flutter documentation isn't very clear about this subject. They only work on one line jsons. What I wanna do is, I wanna get all that data into my phone screen. If I get it, I will show them on a table or a grid. But yet it doesn't won't work. It says type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int' . Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/fluttirci/testJson/db'));

  print(response);
  Map<String, dynamic> userMap = jsonDecode(response.body);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Album.fromJson(userMap); //testing
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class Album {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Album(this.userId, this.id, this.title);

  Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : userId = json['userId'],
        id = json['id'],
        title = json['title'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'userId': userId,
        'id': id,
        'title': title,
      };
}

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<Album> futureAlbum;
  late Future<Album> user;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    user = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
            future: user,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data!.title);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Future<List<Album>> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/fluttirci/testJson/db'));

  print(response);
  Map<String, dynamic> userMap = jsonDecode(response.body);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return (userMap['employees'] as List).map((e) => Album.fromJson(e)).toList()
    
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}
```

then change your FutureBuilder to this:

```
FutureBuilder<List<Album>>(
        future: user,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Album> data = snapshot.data ?? [];

                return ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Column(children: [
                      Text(data[index].title ?? ""),
                    ]);
                  },
                  itemCount: data.length,
                );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('${snapshot.error}');
          }
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      )
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this. And I had to change Future<Album> lines to the Future<List<Album>> too. It works, but not like what I want. It only shows Doe on the screen. I want three of them.

Comment: now Check out my updated answer, you need to a ListView like that. @craghack

Comment: did it fix your issue? @craghack

Comment: Yes it worked now, it prints all of them Doe Smith Jones. Although I got to change my user declaration like this:   

late Future<List<Album>> user;

And you forgot ; somewhere in the program I fixed it by hand :) Thanks a lot mate. Just saying, I don't see much examples like this, why? Is it not common to do it like this?

Comment: glad to help. I don't know, this is a very standard way

Answer (score 0):

Your response.body return a list on `employees` key. And test this model with the response

```dart
Future<List<Album>?> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/fluttirci/testJson/db'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final data = jsonDecode(response.body)["employees"] as List?;
    return data?.map((e) => Album.fromMap(e)).toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class Album {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Album(this.userId, this.id, this.title);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final result = <String, dynamic>{};

    result.addAll({'userId': userId});
    result.addAll({'id': id});
    result.addAll({'title': title});

    return result;
  }

  factory Album.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Album(
      map['userId']?.toInt() ?? 0,
      map['id']?.toInt() ?? 0,
      map['title'] ?? '',
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Album.fromJson(String source) => Album.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late final user = fetchAlbum();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<Album>?>(
          future: user,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                    Text("${snapshot.data?[index].title}"),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('${snapshot.error}');
            }
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It gives some errors:
    E/flutter ( 5885): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(143)] Could not prepare isolate.
E/flutter ( 5885): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/runtime_controller.cc(385)] Could not create root isolate.
E/flutter ( 5885): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(604)] Could not launch engine with configuration.

Comment: needed to rebuild the app I belive

Answer (score 0):

so the `resultMap` should look right like this :

```
    {
  "employees": [
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Doe"
    },
    {
      "userId": 2,
      "id": 3,
      "title": "Smith"
    },
    {
      "userId": 3,
      "id": 4,
      "title": "Jones"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is a map that only has one property, which it values as a `List` of other maps

so accessing `json['userId']` will try to get the `userId` from that map, which doesn't exist in the map

you need to access the `employees` property :

```
json["employees"]
```

then you get the value of it, which is the nested `List` of maps, and now you can access an element in the `List` with its index, then get the `userId` :

```
json["employees"][0]["userId"] // 1
json["employees"][1]["userId"] // 2
json["employees"][2]["userId"] // 3
```

hope this gives you a better approach to what you are trying to do, and what you need to do.

so this :

```
 return Album.fromJson(userMap);
```

should be replaced with this, as an example:

```
 return Album.fromJson(userMap["employees"][0]);
```

here the `userMap["employees"][0]` is :

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 2,
  "title": "Doe"
},
```

and now it should make an `Album` object from it.

if you want to get a List instead of the `List<Map<string, dynamic>>`, you need to iterate over the whole list using the `map` method or with a `for loop`

hope it helps